# Difference between use @RequestMapping with and without method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning about Spring and MVC.

So, in the controller class, I have this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/buscaUsuario/{apodo}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchUser(@PathVariable("apodo") String apodo){
    String res;
    int usrId = this.usuarioService.bucarUsuario(apodo);        
    if(usrId == 0) res = "/error";
    else res =("/user/"+Integer.toString(usrId));
    return ("redirect:"+res);
}
```

And it works. But if I change it deleting the "method=RequestMethod.GET" part. I mean, using it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/buscaUsuario/{apodo}")
public String searchUser(@PathVariable("apodo") String apodo){
    String res;
    int usrId = this.usuarioService.bucarUsuario(apodo);        
    if(usrId == 0) res = "/error";
    else res =("/user/"+Integer.toString(usrId));
    return ("redirect:"+res);
}
```

It ALSO works. So, my question is What's the difference?

Comment: Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping. It says= *The above example does not specify GET vs. PUT, POST, and so forth, because `@RequestMapping` maps all HTTP methods by default. Use `@RequestMapping(method=GET)` or `@GetMapping` to narrow the mapping.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The @RequestMapping annotation handles all types of incoming HTTP request including GET, POST, PUT etc. By default, it’s assumed all incoming requests to URLs are of the HTTP GET kind. To differentiate the mapping by HTTP request type, you need to explicitly specify the HTTP request method. [for more information](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/java/spring/how-spring-controller-request-mapping-works-in-spring-mvc)